# How to run a program installed with playonlinux from linux commandline

Tags: playonlinux

How can I run a program which I have installed via playonlinux directly from a linux commandline or a bash-script?

Answer (score 14):

This is how I did it:

Find the name of the shortcut of the program you want to launch by issuing

```
$ ls ~/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts
```

Then simply

```
$ playonlinux --run "Name of the Program"
```